# Animation of a marker in Mapbox

Tags: html, animation, css-animations, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I'm trying to animate a marker in Mapbox, I found the solution here on Stack overflow... The problem is that I want to make a sort of combination of this two features:
-- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-marker/
-- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/free-camera-path/
In a few words, I want to follow the marker during its path.
Is it possible to do? Thank you so much

I tried to combine the two codes that I found on Mpabox's site, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine the two examples to get the wanted effect.

I have made the camera's position directly above the marker and look at the marker, creating a follow camera above the marker.

I have done this by setting the camera in the animation function and setting the location of the camera to be the same as the marker using `marker._lngLat`.

```js
// TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
// ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
// https://account.mapbox.com
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGJyb2NrbWFubiIsImEiOiJjajgxbnlqbGg2enR4MnhxbXllaHYzOGNzIn0.mA9mk90HM6ePh0gQq_55yw';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  // Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2
});

// Add a new Marker.
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
  color: '#F84C4C' // color it red
});

// Define the animation.
function animateMarker(timestamp) {
  const radius = 20;

  /* 
  Update the data to a new position 
  based on the animation timestamp. 
  The divisor in the expression `timestamp / 1000` 
  controls the animation speed.
   */
  marker.setLngLat([
    Math.cos(timestamp / 1000) * radius,
    Math.sin(timestamp / 1000) * radius
  ]);

  /* 
  Ensure the marker is added to the map. 
  This is safe to call if it's already added.
  */
  marker.addTo(map);

  const camera = map.getFreeCameraOptions();
  const cameraAltitude = 4000000;

  // set the position and altitude of the camera above the marker
  camera.position = mapboxgl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
      lng: marker._lngLat.lng,
      lat: marker._lngLat.lat
    },
    cameraAltitude
  );

  // tell the camera to look at the marker
  camera.lookAtPoint({
    lng: marker._lngLat.lng,
    lat: marker._lngLat.lat
  });

  map.setFreeCameraOptions(camera);

  // Request the next frame of the animation.
  requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
}

// Start the animation.
requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.13.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```